# How to add minutes in moment js with a HH:mm format?

Tags: momentjs

How do I add minutes to this. I followed the documentation but somehow this is not working:

```
var hours = randomIntFromInterval(0,23);
var minutes = randomIntFromInterval(0,59);
var time = moment(hours+':'+minutes,'HHmm').format("HH:mm");
time.add(7,'m');
```

Only the last line is not working, but should be right according to the documentation. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) returns a string, you have to use [`add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) on moment object.

Your code could be like the following:

```js
var hours = randomIntFromInterval(0,23);
var minutes = randomIntFromInterval(0,59);
var time = moment(hours+':'+minutes,'HH:mm');
time.add(7,'m');
console.log(time.format("HH:mm"));
```

Note that you can create a moment object using [`moment(Object)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/) method instead of parsing a string, in your case:

```js
moment({hours: hours, minutes: minutes});
```

As the docs says:

> Omitted units default to 0 or the current date, month, and year

Answer (score -6):

You can use IF condition to see if minutes < 10

to add "0" like 07,08

`var d = new Date() var n = d.getMinutes() if(n<10) n="0"+n;`

But watch out you will have to slice that zero if you want to increment.

EDIT: I was young when wrote this.
A better approach is:
moment(YOUR_DATE).format('HH:mm')